# If-else statement with multiple conditions in microsoft excel

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, nested-if

Is there a formula in Microsoft Excel 2007 wherein I can have multiple "else" statement if a specific keyword is found in the cell that I'm calling. For example, if cell C3 contains the word "Network" it will automatically input "5" in cell B3, otherwise if it contains the word "Software", it will input "4" in cell B3 and so on. I've tried using this code below but it shows error

```
=IF(OR(SEARCH("Har",C5)),"6", IF(SEARCH("Soft", C5)), "7","")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for your 2 examples shown

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("Network",A3))),5,IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("Software",A3))),4,"-"))
```

---

*what if I need to find two keywords for example if cell A3 contains either "Network" or "Hardware" it will return 5*

```
=IF(OR(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("Network",A4))),NOT(ISERROR(FIND("Software",A4)))),5,"-")
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked! Just a follow-up question, what if I need to find two keywords for example if cell A3 contains either "Network" or "Hardware" it will return 5.

Comment: Updated solution

Comment: Hi, is it possible if I look for the specific keyword from a range of cells? For example, ("Network", A4 *to* H4)

Comment: Please post a new question- in the future, try to avoid asking middle man questions as it appears this is not what you actually need. Think your problem through before posting to ensure you ask for what you really need- I’ve already answered 2 separate questions